# Identify 32 bit or 64 bit Windows 7 installation folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have couple of Windows 7 installation folder in my machine.

How can I identify which one is 32 bit and 64 bit ?

I tried checking few .ini and .inf files but none of it could give me a hint.

Is there a way to check a file from installation folder which would tell me its 32 bit or 64 bit or both ?

Comment: System32 for 32 bit, and SysWOW64 for 64bit? Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: No, This is after the installation. I am talking about the installation cd itself, contents of ISO.

Comment: In ISO do you have, WinSxS which is ~3gb for 32bit  and for 64bit ~6gb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the autorun file.

For 64bit you will see the lines:

```
[AutoRun.Amd64]

open=sources\sperr32.exe x64
```

Also, on 64bit installs, on the root of the drive you will see this file:

```
Bootmgr.efi
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way for checking is Go to drive.../efi/boot/

If **bootai32.efi** or **bootai86.efi** or **bootx32.efi** or **bootx32.efi** is present, OS is 32 bit.

If **bootax64.efi** or **bootai64.efi** is present, OS is 64 bit.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

NightLightStriker

Answer (score -1):

Use unknown decompressed image as an install? Great fun, you should try on occasion. The problem is that the `install.wim` can be any.

Well, yeah, let's cleave to autorun.inf which is not strongly associated with the installation file, and the team will be useful to us after this distribution will be installed).

Look at the environment variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`

```
echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
```

Get full OS name:

```
wmic os get caption
```

Comment: He is asking about the installation media. These will only provide post-installation information.