# Getting Windows 10 from "Non Genuine" Windows 7 Gateway

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, windows-10

My SO bought a computer from Gateway which originally came with a copy of Windows 7 installed.  She did not keep the OEM install disk when she received the desktop.

After her OS crashed, I attempted to reinstall with a copy of Windows 7 that I purchased independent of the OEM manufacturer.  It was a legitimate version, but because it was not Gateway's version, the hardware insists that the OS is not "genuine".

The problem is that the Gateway is out of warranty, and Microsoft can't help (I've called their tech support).  To get a copy of Gateway's OS, I would have to pay something like $100+ to access their tech support, and get a key that agrees with their hardware.

However, Windows 10 has recently been released, and upgrades on it are also $100+ dollars.  I would prefer to just buy Windows 10, and circumvent Gateway entirely.

My questions is:  if a legitimate copy of Windows 7 does not cooperate with the hardware, how can I know if a legitimate copy of Windows 10 will cooperate with the hardware?  I'm concerned that if I just buy a copy of Windows 10, that Gateway will still want their cut, and their hardware will tell the OS that it's not a legitimate version.

Comment: This copy you bought sounds fishy.  Besides this gateway computer, should have a COA, you can use that to install the legit license.  I don't know who you have talked to in the past but you got some really bad answers

Comment: The issue is that it's a desktop that I removed from its original case to upgrade the power supply.  Didn't think twice about keeping the key, and just to get a hold of Gateway support, I had to ask this: http://superuser.com/questions/882182/find-serial-number-of-gateway-without-case

Answer (score 3):

That's usually not how it works. Licence keys are linked to specific Windows editions. The laptop's licence key is linked to a specific Gateway OEM version, that you usually can't just download or exchange with an independent store-bought copy. The latter one, presumably being the one you unsuccessfully tried to install.

That means that if you buy an independent copy of Windows (one that is "unbranded" and not OEM), you should be able to install and activate it without any problems. That said, you should be able to activate the Windows 7 installation with the key that came with your store-bought copy on the Gateway laptop but not with the one you would find on the licence key sticker on the laptop itself.

You can either activate using the key that came with the copy that you now installed, buy a fresh copy of Windows 10, or you can buy a copy of Windows 7 or 8 and use the free upgrade programme.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind shelling out the $100, you can buy a new full version of either Windows 7 (and then get the free windows 10 upgrade), or just buy a full version of Windows 10 from your favorite e-retailer.

Here's the links on NewEgg:

Windows 10 - [http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832416892&cm_re=windows_7-*-32-416-892-*-Product](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832416892&cm_re=windows_7-_-32-416-892-_-Product)

Windows 7 - [http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832416806&cm_re=windows_7-*-32-416-806-*-Product](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832416806&cm_re=windows_7-_-32-416-806-_-Product)

**Note:** Be sure to check which version of the OS you need (64bit or 32bit).  You can google for instructions if you're not sure how: [Identify 32 bit or 64 bit Windows 7 installation folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/566223/identify-32-bit-or-64-bit-windows-7-installation-folder)